# Contact form gives error, does not trigger action php script

Tags: php, email

I know that this question might already be answered, but I just cant find particular case as I got, and it's been a while now.

So, my  contact form looks like this:

```
 <div id="contact-form">
    <div id="message"></div>
    <form method="POST" action="php/contact.php" name="contactform" id="contactform">
        <input name="name" type="text" id="name" class="inputForm2" onclick="this.select()" value="Name">
        <input name="email" type="text" id="email" onclick="this.select()" value="E-mail">
        <textarea name="comments" id="comments" onclick="this.select()">Message</textarea>
        <input type="submit" class="send_message transition" id="submit" value="Send Message">
    </form>
</div>
```

And php script

```
function isEmail($email) { Skipped this one to save space }

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

$name     = $_POST['name'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$content = $_POST['comments'];


if(trim($name) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Enter your name.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($email) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Enter a valid email address.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!isEmail($email)) {
    echo '<div class="error_message">You have enter an invalid e-mail address, try again.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($content) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Enter your message.</div>';
    exit();
} 

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $comments = stripslashes($comments);
}

$emailTo = "x@y";

$subject = 'Youve been contacted by ' . $name . '.';

$e_body = "You have been contacted by: $name" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_reply = "E-mail: $email\r\nPhone: $phone";
$e_content = "Message:\r\n$comments" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

//$content = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply, 70 );

$headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

if(mail($emailTo, $subject, $content, $headers)) {

    echo "<fieldset>";
    echo "<div id='success_page'>";
    echo "<h3>Email Sent Successfully.</h3>";
    echo "<p>Thank you <strong>$name</strong>, your message has been submitted to us.</p>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</fieldset>";

} else {

    echo 'ERROR!';
}
```

Could you point me what's wrong with this?

Comment: what is the problem? whats happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First ensure that you have `contact.php` in php folder and also check whether your html form is reaching to php code or not because i can see onclick method in your html form .if your html form is reaching to php then

you have problem in `isEmail($email)` function .if you are using  `isemail` function then you have to return true because you are checking `else if(!isEmail($email)) {` in validation please update as below

```
function isEmail($email) { 

     return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
     }
```

full code

```
  function isEmail($email) { 

         return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
         }

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

$name     = $_POST['name'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$content = $_POST['comments'];


if(trim($name) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Enter your name.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($email) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Enter a valid email address.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!isEmail($email)) {
    echo '<div class="error_message">You have enter an invalid e-mail address, try again.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($content) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Enter your message.</div>';
    exit();
} 

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $comments = stripslashes($comments);
}

$emailTo = "e.lucinskas@hotmail.co.uk";

$subject = 'Youve been contacted by ' . $name . '.';

$e_body = "You have been contacted by: $name" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_reply = "E-mail: $email\r\nPhone: $phone";
$e_content = "Message:\r\n$comments" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

//$content = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply, 70 );

$headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

if(mail($emailTo, $subject, $content, $headers)) {

    echo "<fieldset>";
    echo "<div id='success_page'>";
    echo "<h3>Email Sent Successfully.</h3>";
    echo "<p>Thank you <strong>$name</strong>, your message has been submitted to us.</p>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</fieldset>";

} else {

    echo 'ERROR!';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for such a quick reply, I have tried your code. It seems i still get error in when submit the form. I believe it fails on if(mail($emailTo, $subject, $content, $headers))  part. I have added to show me $emailTo on error too, it seems that it gets all values right, just for some reason mail function gives false. Maybe my hosting is not configured properly and server itself blocks emails? 
I am using VPS with Win2012 and Plesk. 


http://prntscr.com/czslbl

Comment: Indeed. Went through logs and discovered a message: 

PHP Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 503 This mail server requires authentication when attempting to send to a non-local e-mail address. Please check your mail client settings or contact your administrator to verify that the domain or address is defined for this server. in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\ernest-l.com\httpdocs\php\contact.php on line 50